# How to access param in parent component with React Router DOM

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

My routes are like

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <App>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/:locale?" component={Home}/>
    </Switch>
  </App>
</BrowserRouter>
```

App component is

```
class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.match) {
            console.log(this.props.match);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting undefined here. This only works for Home component.

I need some workaround for changing language state according to `:locale` for every Route. I don't want to do this manually for every route component.

Comment: Have you tried using `exact` keyword before `path` inside your `route`?

Comment: yes, but `:locale` is still `undefined`

Comment: How are you accessing the `route`?
From where you are passing the value of `locale`?

Comment: I'm navigating to `localhost:3000/en` so that `props.match.locale` should be `en`. This works if put same code in all routes. I want to get it in `App` that wraps all of routes as its children.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to render `App` inside a `Route`, you can use the `withRouter` HOC provided by `react-router`. In your App component:

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  ...
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Comment: I don't think you can access the `locale` param since the `/:locale?` route is being rendered after/inside the `App` component. You should just set some state in App for the locale. If you want to have locale available everywhere you can use Context